# id not Auto Incrementing on Postgres 12.2 using SQL Inserts

Tags: postgresql

On PostgresSQL 12.2, running on macOS Catalina (10.15.4), have the following DB Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE public.reservation
(
    id integer,
    name character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default"
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.reservation
    OWNER to postgres;
```

---

Here's listing the relations:

```
orders=# \d
            List of relations
 Schema |    Name     | Type  |  Owner   
--------+-------------+-------+----------
 public | reservation | table | postgres
(1 row)
```

---

After conducting the following inserts:

```
INSERT INTO reservation(name) VALUES('Michael');
INSERT INTO reservation(name) VALUES('Vito');
INSERT INTO reservation(name) VALUES('Sonny');
INSERT INTO reservation(name) VALUES('Fredo');
```

---

Then, checking the results:

```
SELECT * FROM reservation;
```

---

Receive the following output:

```
 id |  name  
----+--------
    | Michael
    | Vito
    | Sonny
    | Fredo
(4 rows)
```

---

How can I modify this table's structure (using DDL) to have it auto-increment ids with values?

Comment: Are you aware that a limit of `255` for a varchar column has no performance or storage advantage over 250, 263 or 3876

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Nope, I was not aware... I am coming from a MySQL background and transitioning to PostgreSQL and am following an online tutorial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just because you name a column `id`, doesn't mean it's an "auto increment" column. If you want that, you need to declare it as an identity column:

```
CREATE TABLE public.reservation
(
    id integer not null generated always as identity,
    name character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres, use **SERIAL** datatype for auto-increment integer id.

Run the below queries

```
CREATE SEQUENCE public.reservation_id_seq
    INCREMENT 1
    START 1
    MINVALUE 1
    MAXVALUE 2147483647
    CACHE 1;

ALTER SEQUENCE public.reservation_id_seq
    OWNER TO postgres;
```

AND THEN

```
CREATE TABLE public.reservation
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 
    nextval('public.reservation_id_seq'::regclass),
    name character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default"
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.reservation
    OWNER to postgres;
```

Thank you !!

Comment: With modern Postgres version using `identity` columns is preferred over `serial`: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_serial

Comment: @Prateek Sharma - Thank you but can you kind of explain why I needed to use sequence for this? Sorry, I come from a MySQL background.

Comment: sequence is to track the latest id in an incremental order. It always +1 in the current id.

Comment: @PacificNW_Lover: you don't have to use sequences explicitly. An `identity` (or `serial`) column will do that automatically for you in the background.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - How can I use ```identity`` instead of ```serial```? Can you provide an example?